# One of the Powershell Command is not working in a script but works if run on the command prompt

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following 2 commands.

Command 1:

```
Get-QCSyncHistoryStep -Workflow "CSV2AD" -Name "Provision from CSV to 31AD" -Count 1 | ForEach {$_.SuccessOperations} | Out-File c:\scripts\temp1.txt
```

Command 2:

```
Get-QCSyncHistorySummaryRun * | Out-File c:\scripts\temp2.txt
```

**Command 1** works only on powershell prompt but not as a script. Where as **command 2** works on both prompt and when used in script file.

If I run both the command in a script file, the command 1 is not writing anything into the file where as command 2 dose.

Need help in deciphering the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove piping and start assigning results to variables. Check which assignment provides empty value and start debugging there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that Out-File overwrites the contents of the destination file unless you specify the `-Append` switch, which can still be used if the file doesn't already exist. I'm not familiar with the `Get-QCSyncHistory*` cmdlets or their output (are they your own functions?), but I suppose that if you pipe the objects in the output through a foreach loop and the final object has a null-valued **SuccessOperations** parameter, then you'll effectively just wipe the file you have been trying to write to.